# Convert JSON response to Graph.EducationAssignment Object

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

When I attempt to convert a JSON response to a `Graph.EducationAssignment` root Object there is no data. I get no error message, just an empty object.

I'm calling `/beta/education/classes/{classId}/assignments`

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(webApiUrl);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment Assignments =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment>(json);

    // List<Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment> Assignments1 =
    //    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment>>(json);
}
```

Due to the size of the response, here is the first line, which shows that the assignments are held in an array.

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#education/classes('id')/assignments",
  "value": [
    {
      "classId": "blah-blah",
      "displayName": "The homeless",
      "closeDateTime": null
```

I'd appreciate it if somebody could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe what `Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment` looks like or where it came from. The most likely issue is that you're trying to deserialize a collection of resources (which is contained in `value`) into a single object.

Unless you're familiar with OData and JSON serialization, I'd avoid trying to hand-craft your own Graph client. You will have a much easier time using the [Microsoft Graph Beta SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet). The SDK will handle all of this for you and you'll end up with cleaner code:

```
var assignments = await graphClient
    .Education
    .Classes["id"]
    .Assignments
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var assignment = await graphClient
    .Education
    .Classes["id"]
    .Assignments["id"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: I was getting information from [List Assignments]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-list-assignments?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: From what I understand, Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment is a built-in class. e.g. 
Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment Assignments = new Microsoft.Graph.EducationAssignment();

Comment: If you're using the SDK, why are you not using it to populate the object?